# How to cleanly uninstall anaconda via terminal. I am having trouble getting coremltools to found as a module in Spyder

Tags: macos, python-2.7, xcode9, coreml

[Image of installed Anaconda Directories](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Po4zQ.jpg) OK, long story short. I just started learning about CoreML for iOS. So from what i gathered, theres only about 4 trained models on Apple's website. In the search of some more robust models, i found Caffe was a hugely mentioned one. You need to use python to be able to translate some of these other 'external' models. I installed Anaconda via the continuum website for mac and am using the only supported 2.7 python language with keras/scikit/and a few other modules....... So from what I think it could be is after I installed anaconda at Applications level on my mac, it should of been originally installed at the User level. I reinstalled it at the User level, so technically I have two instances of anaconda on my system. Neither will work and inside Anaconda, i cannot import coremltools.

I have a hunch that maybe i need to change some pointers. Or just uninstall it completely from the machine and reinstall it at the User level from the start. I have about a year of swift experience, so im much more confident in my swift ability vs terminal ability. If anyone could coach me through how to cleanly remove it from my macbook pro, and explain the commands, I would greatly appreciate it. Or give any insight about whats going on or what im not doing. I can go into more detail if need be. Cheers in advance

Comment: Who knows what you need? It could be anything. To cleanly uninstall anaconda: `rm -rf ~/anaconda`. Repeat (with `sudo`) if you also have a version in `/Applications`. When installing other python libraries, check that you are using the Anaconda Python version of `pip`, etc., to install them -- and that they end up inside the anaconda library.

Comment: Hello and welcome to StackOverflow. Please take some time to read the help page, especially the sections named ["What topics can I ask about here?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). And more importantly, please read [the Stack Overflow question checklist](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/156810/204922). You might also want to learn about [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Examples](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: after the initial rm -rf ~/anaconda, terminal says directory not empty. and after the same with sudo, i input my password and it seems nothing happened. thank you for the speedy response btw Alexis